# How do I remove an entire element when it is clipped?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a list of items in an unordered list inside a div with overflow hidden. The items in the list are represented by boxes with text content and a border round them. It can be a long list of useful, but not essential information, that can be hidden if used on a smaller device.

If some items in the list overflow, I would like to set the entire item that overflows as hidden, not just part of it.

Currently, the list can look like this when clipped:

```
---------
|   A   |
|       |
---------

---------
|   B   |
```

Since B overflows only half of it is displayed. I would like only A to be displayed if this occurs.

The items do not have to be in an unordered list, can be in whatever. Is it any way to do this using only HTML and CSS?

Comment: I don't think there's a simple solution to this problem using only html and css. The only way I can think of doing this would be to make sure that each item within the list is the same height as the containing div that has the overflow:hidden property.

Comment: Do you know anything prior to the display about the heights of the overflow box and the list items? Or is everything totally random?

Comment: I decided to use jQuery, I just wondered if you gurus had a better way :-). the overflow area is of a fixed width but random length, the boxes have a fixed number of lines so the length is known.

Answer (score 13):

It is possible with the "Flex" property.

In the snippet below, make the window display width smaller. You will see whatever list items that don't fit are removed completely until the window gets bigger again.

It is a bit hokey in that it is adding the bullet using the `li:before` clause, but it works nonetheless.

```css
.box {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 8px 16px 8px 0;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 15px;
}
    
ul {
    height: 90px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 15px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 0;
}
    
li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
    
li:before {
    content: '\2022';
    position: absolute;
    left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>these LI's are dynamically generated</li>
        <li>I have no idea of their length ahead of time</li>
        <li>Seth Rollins</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>A very long item that takes up two lines (at least I hope so)</li>
        <li>Another list item that takes up at least one line(trust me on this)</li>
        <li>List item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The key properties here are:

- `display: flex`. It uses flex box on the parent.
- `flex-direction: column` makes sure that the order of elements is vertical. -  While `flex-wrap: wrap` wraps any overflowing element to another column.

This can be shortened to:

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: column wrap;
```

If all child elements are behaving in such a way that they are covering the entire width of their parent. Then that means any overflowing elements are wrapped into another column, effectively being hidden from view and avoiding any clipping.