# CSS overflow option to hide whole element, not clip it

Tags: html, css

This is what I have at the moment:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="create-new-btn"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Create new...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>My profile</a></li>
</ul>
```

And for the container:

```css
#pando-header-c {
  position:absolute;
  left:100px;
  right:430px;
  height:50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:block; 
}
```

However, for some reason it renders the elements partially and it doesn't fully cut them out in the overflow; despite the fact that I've set them all to inline-block and block (the a, as well as li).

This is how it clips it:

[image: example]

The question is how do I make the whole element invisible if it doesn't fit entirely, instide of clipping the text out.

Comment: remove white-space:nowrap, so it breaks into lines as long as there is not enough room for next inline-block element. You should make a snippet showing your issue to get clear/adapted answers  ... http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/XXVobP doesn't help you much ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591254/css-remove-entire-element-when-clipped

Answer (score 2):

Overflow is, by definition, the things that don't fit. So `hidden` means "hide the overflow", not the element. The best way I can think of to hide it if it doesn't fit is to use media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #pando-header-c {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

It takes some tweaking on your end to see, but there's not a CSS way I can think of to hide it if the content is larger than the container.

Comment: Thanks, althought the issue is that I tried to work around media queries so that I can have some elements display, instead of hiding them all. I can do this for all of them, but it'll be rather hard to make drastic changes later on.